# C# Programatically allow user to access AD Application

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have quite a strange situation.

Basically i have an app which is registered in Azure. I need to set the 'Require User Assignment' option in AD which is fine. However, once a particular step is completed by the HR department on the app, i then need to allow the user to access the app. Is this possible at all?

I know it is quite a strange request but i cannot seem to find anything on google (could be googling the wrong terms) but it would surprise me if this wasnt possible at all.

Comment: Your program can access AD using Principal Context.  I am not sure about Azure AD but you could start with this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yeah i use that functionality elsewhere to get e.g. a user's manager from local AD, and i can access the Azure AD using the graph API however, i am struggling to work out how to maintain user's access to the app itself